# How to get the developer key for youtube API?

Tags: youtube-api

I am using gdata yt_service which requires a developer key. Couldn't find any resource pointing to developer key. Does the yt_service still work or is it outdated?

Answer (score 0):

I think the service still works. You could follow the guide here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Im69kzhpR3I to help you. Since google code is shutting down, the new console is at https://console.developers.google.com/. You should find what you're looking for there.

Comment: There is no specific key named developer key mentioned in the video.